# Run as command not showing server

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, jakarta-ee

i want to add existing project in eclipse works space, the project was successfully added in works space,after i want  to run that project in Apache tomcat server ,the run as command not shown my listed server ,here i attach the screen shot, please help me. Thanks for advance.

[Screenshot of my eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPCcq.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the image you posted your project *Quiz* is simple Java project. You need to "convert" it to web project in order to be able to run it on web server. To do that you need to

- right click on the project in Project Explorer
- select *Properties* from menu (the Properties window will show up)
- click on *Project Facets*
- on the right side you need to click the link *Convert to faceted form...* (Project Facets will show up)
- in the *Project Facet* list check *Dynamic Web Module* checkbox (note you can configure your web directory and generating of *web.xml* after clicking the link *Further configuration available*)
- click *OK*

And that's it. Your project is now ready to be run on a web server.

Comment: Glad to be of help. Please accept my answer since it solved your problem.